# How to display current time using ng-forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular8

Display current time using `ng-forms`

```html
<input
  type="time"
  class="form-control"
  path="time"
  formControlName="time"
  [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.time.errors}"
/>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This one too**

You can use the Angular2 Date Pipe to display a JavaScript Date object. Check the docs (linked) for the correct formatting that you are looking for.

**Solution 1** :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'date-pipe',
  template: `<div>
    <p>Today is {{today | date}}</p>
    <p>Or if you prefer, {{today | date:'fullDate'}}</p>
    <p>The time is {{today | date:'jmZ'}}</p>
    <p>Finally the date and time is {{today | date:'short'}}</p>
  </div>`
})
export class DatePipeComponent {
  today: number = Date.now();
}
```

**Solution 2** :

```
{{date  | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

**Solution 3** :

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common'
...
constructor(public datepipe: DatePipe){}
...
myFunction(){
 this.date=new Date();
 let latest_date =this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

Comment: Thank you,for the Answer bro,but i have been already tried with date,it is working in firefox but ,type="time" is not working in firefox.

Comment: Thanks,it is working in chrome,and not in firfox.